# What is the etymology of the name of the River Cherwell in England?

Tags: etymology, names, proper-nouns, toponyms

The River Cherwell is the second largest tributary of the Thames after the River Kennet. What is the etymology of its name?

I could not find any etymology after checking several websites.

Comment: "Well" used also to mean "spring" as is a place where water rises from the ground but I've no idea where the "cher" part comes from. However the Kennet and Cherwell are a long way from.being the largest rivers in England: they are both tributaries of the Thames which is almost five times the length of the Kennet and almost six times the length of the Cherwell. The Severn is about the same length as the Thames and the Trent nearly as long. Have you missed a part of your description of the Cherwell and Kennet?

Comment: @KillingTime, @BoldBen; I meant to write "is the second largest tributary of the Thames." Apparently I was in a rush and didn't know what I was talking about. :(

Comment: Galactic: To save duplication, could you please indicate what your research has shown?